# datetime.strptime not taking argument passed by custom function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to create a reusable def function that converts a Julian date in a pandas dataframe column into a Gregorian style date.  When using the function, I get a TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df.head()

    SDKCOO   SDDOCO       DATE_GL
0   00308   6118002.0   118337.0
1   00308   6118002.0   118337.0
2   00308   6118002.0   118337.0

in:  df['DATE_GL'].dtype
out: dtype('float64')

def my_func(x):
    x = x.astype(str)
    year = x.str[1:3]
    jday = x.str[3:6]
    x = year + jday
    x = x.astype(str)
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%y%j') #this line gives me the issue
    return x

df['DATE_GL'] = my_func(df['DATE_GL'])
```

Then I get this TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bc5147e6c807> in <module>
----> 1 df['DATE_GL'] = my_func(df['DATE_GL'])

<ipython-input-3-c25482ba9377> in my_func(x)
      5     x = year + jday
      6     x = x.astype(str)
----> 7     x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%y%j')
      8     return x

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

I can achieve my desired output as follows, but I have to modify the above function and also use an apply method with a lambda function to achieve it, which is what I don't want.  I want everything to flow through the function so that I can easily call it and apply it to other dataframes that have the same date formatting issue.

Desired output:

```
    SDKCOO  SDDOCO      DATE_GL
0   00308   6118002.0   2018-12-03
1   00308   6118002.0   2018-12-03
2   00308   6118002.0   2018-12-03
```

Here is the modified function and additional apply code line that helps me achieve the results I want above.

```
def my_func(x):
    x = x.astype(str)
    year = x.str[1:3]
    jday = x.str[3:6]
    x = year + jday
    x = x.astype(str)
    return x

df['DATE_GL'] = df['DATE_GL'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%y%j'))
```

Why can't I get the desired result by having everything flow through my def function?  What is causing the TypeError issue?  I converted "x" to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime just works with individual strings, not with series as you have. When you send df['DATE_GL'] to your function, you are sending the three values of the column.
To work with a complete column of a dataframe you should change:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%y%j')
to
   x = pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%y%j')

Your code should be like this:

```
def my_func(x):
    x = x.astype(str)
    year = x.str[1:3]
    jday = x.str[3:6]
    x = year + jday
    x = x.astype(str)
    x = pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%y%j')
    return x

df['DATE_GL'] = my_func(df['DATE_GL'])
```

Comment: This works and was exactly what I needed! Thanks for explaining how datetime.datetime does not work on a series and for suggesting the pd.to_datetime.  I have never used that before.

Answer (score 1):

Probably worth noting that you can achieve the same without a custom function:

```
df['DATE_GL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_GL'].astype(str).str[1:6], format='%y%j')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as well and I may use this personally for my own uses when doing the date conversion, but I selected Pablo's answer as the best answer because I needed to build this into a function so when I roll it out to other users at my company it will be easier for them to essentially apply the function.  Trying to simply and use as little code as possible for them.  Thanks for your suggestion.